# Eloquent model setRelation generating array instead of Collection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

If you are doing `$instance = $model->with('categories')->find($id);` and after `var_dump($instance->categories)` it going to return Collection of categories.

But on the project I'm working on in some heavy queries, we are not using with and getting data with a combination of `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCAT`, like this:

`\DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(categories.id, ",,", categories.name) SEPARATOR ";;") as categories'),`

And then we are building relations manually parsing result and creating a relationship using `$instance->setRelation($relation, $data)` but for some reason, it's returning an array of objects instead of Collection.

There are also option to use `setRelations()` and this method returning Collection but I found if you have bidirectional relations it's creating recursion and working really slow. For example: if in `User` model we have set `$this->hasMany('Comments')` and in `Comments` model we have set return `$this->belongsTo('User')`; and after when we running `setRelations()` to manually build relations it is create nesting models with recursion (User->Comments->User and so on).

The third option is to not use `setRelation()` or `setRelations()` and just to manually create Collection, populating it and set to model. But in such case, it will not be set as a model relation.

Any suggestions on how to build manually in the right way (to create relation is same way eloquent creating with `with`).

Comment: you can try  `$instance->setRelation('relation', $data->values()->all());` `group` return collection of collection, using `->values()` removed the keys from group by collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group return collection of collection so you have to remove the keys of first collection and for that you can use `values` function of collection like this

```
$instance->setRelation('relation', $data->values()->all());
```

Details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-values